# My cars wheel makes kla klak when driving 60 to 80 kms per hour,but the outer cv and wheel bearing is changed

Tags: noise

[image: klak sound on wheel]inside of wheel not sure if this could be the problem

Comment: What is the year/make/model/engine of the car in question?

Answer (score 0):

That link circled is part of the steering system.  Its a link that connects the steering rack to the outer hub.  That should be tight with absolutely no free play. It's a part of the system that steers your car when you turn your steering wheel.  The part you've circled is called the "outer tie rod end" in the image below.  Note, if your outer tie rod is loose, its a major safety issue.  Do NOT drive the car until it's fixed.

[image: Front Wheel Drive system]

With that said, my guess is somebody did some maintenance on your car and forgot to re-install the stabilizer/sway bar links.  If they are just hanging free, you will definitely hear a irregular rattle noise at different vehicle speeds.  Terminology Note: Sway bar = Stabilizer Bar = Stabar  The stabilizer bar helps drive performance by reducing the body roll of a vehicle during fast cornering or over road irregularities.

Typically the sway bar has short links to connect between the lower control arm and the front struts.  In the image below, the sway bar link is the dog bone shaped thing on the right.

[image: Sta Bar links]

I'm guessing yours isn't correctly attached at both ends, or its loose..  Looking at your photo, the sway bar link is that small silver colored round bar that is just peeking out from behind the rubber CV joint boot in the photo. Its oriented up and down. Crawl under the car a bit, grab that bar and shake it hard.  Do this on both sides of the car.  Is it tight and secured?  Make sure vehicle is in secure before you do that.  Safety first.

Comment: Thanks so much for your feedback appreciate it so much,no that klak klak sound was before the outer cv joint and wheelbearing was replaced,after that parts was replaced the car made that sound again on that exact same speed as i mentioned above

Comment: When you got under the car and shook the silver staybar links on both sides of car were they tight?